# Water Damage to Bathroom Vanity

Tags: bathroom, water-damage, vanity

I think some water damage around our sink has caused the wood in the vanity to swell and split. It’s relatively new (a couple of years) and we’ve only been living in the house for a few months. Is there anything we can do to repair the damage? Or do we have to accept it’s going to not look so nice and will potentially need replacing?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Or this? [How to fix the damaged floor of a vanity cabinet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/211491/how-to-fix-the-damaged-floor-of-a-vanity-cabinet)

Comment: Or this? [Covering damaged wood cabinet under sink](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/138254/covering-damaged-wood-cabinet-under-sink)

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer with some visual context. I can't tell what I'm looking at there.

Answer (score 3):

There is no fix to repair that section except replacing.

It looks like MDF or pressed wood(wood chips glued together) and that type is ruined if water gets in it.

Will need to make sure that it is kept dry, not damp, to prevent further damage and mold growth.

Depending if there is no more damage to the rest for the vanity, might just need to replace the top, or might find it easier to replace the whole thing.

Comment: Does depend on how well it sealed from water.  My 40 plus year old fake wood kitchen and bathrooms are still good, and not from being that careful with splashing water.

Comment: Cabinets are rarely built from MDF. This is good ol' particle board.